# Volley authfailure error when sending data from mobile (android) to Wamp server

Tags: java, android, authentication, android-volley

I am using SQL for my database. I have cross-verified all names of the variables and parameters they are correct. I have cross-verified my PHP script using postman snd I am getting correct output but when moving on to send data from the mobile I am getting com.android.volley.authfailureError.

Following is my android code...

```
package com.example.researchprojectv2;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.android.volley.AuthFailureError;
import com.android.volley.DefaultRetryPolicy;
import com.android.volley.Request;
import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.VolleyError;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest;

import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private EditText emp_ID, password;
    private Button btn_submit;
    private TextView txt;
    private ProgressDialog progressDialog;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        emp_ID = findViewById(R.id.editTextNumber);
        password = findViewById(R.id.editTextTextPassword);
        btn_submit = findViewById(R.id.button);
        txt = findViewById(R.id.login);
        progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);

        txt.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Login.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });

        btn_submit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                registerUser();
                progressDialog.show();
                progressDialog.setTitle("Please while registering");
            }
        });
    }

    private void registerUser() {
        final String empID = emp_ID.getText().toString().trim();
        final String passWD = password.getText().toString().trim();

        progressDialog.setMessage("Registering User....");

        StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST,
                Constants.URL_REGISTER,
                new Response.Listener<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String response) {
                        progressDialog.hide();

                        try {

                            JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), jsonObject.getString(
                                    "message"), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, hhh.class);
                            startActivity(intent);

                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }

                    }
                },
                new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), error.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        progressDialog.hide();
                    }
                }) {

            @Override
            protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
                Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();
                params.put("emp_id", empID);
                params.put("password", passWD);
                return params;
            }
        };

        //200000 is the time in milliseconds adn is equal to 200 sec
        stringRequest.setRetryPolicy(new DefaultRetryPolicy(
                200000,
                DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_MAX_RETRIES,
                DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT));

        RequestHandler.getInstance(this).addToRequestQueue(stringRequest);
    }
}
```

log report (android studio)

```
07/05 01:00:34: Launching 'app' on Xiaomi Redmi Note 7 Pro.
$ adb shell am start -n "com.example.researchprojectv2/com.example.researchprojectv2.MainActivity" -a android.intent.action.MAIN -c android.intent.category.LAUNCHER
Connected to process 19184 on device 'xiaomi-redmi_note_7_pro-5a14c494'.
Capturing and displaying logcat messages from application. This behavior can be disabled in the "Logcat output" section of the "Debugger" settings page.
I/searchprojectv: Late-enabling -Xcheck:jni
W/searchprojectv: miui_dex2oat: DeoptimizeBootImage: patch entry points of methods in boot image to interpreter bridge
W/searchprojectv: miui_dex2oat:　OatFile: /data/app/com.example.researchprojectv2-R6-g_SKERFwg6QfVgTpG1A==/oat/arm64/base.odex Compiler-Filter = speed-profile
I/Perf: Connecting to perf service.
W/searchprojectv: Accessing hidden method Landroid/view/View;->computeFitSystemWindows(Landroid/graphics/Rect;Landroid/graphics/Rect;)Z (light greylist, reflection)
W/searchprojectv: Accessing hidden method Landroid/view/ViewGroup;->makeOptionalFitsSystemWindows()V (light greylist, reflection)
I/Adreno: QUALCOMM build                   : 89f10b9, I3d0e3ac366
    Build Date                       : 12/25/18
    OpenGL ES Shader Compiler Version: EV031.25.14.03
    Local Branch                     : 
    Remote Branch                    : 
    Remote Branch                    : 
    Reconstruct Branch               : 
    Build Config                     : S P 6.0.9 AArch64
I/Adreno: PFP: 0x016ee177, ME: 0x00000000
I/ConfigStore: android::hardware::configstore::V1_0::ISurfaceFlingerConfigs::hasWideColorDisplay retrieved: 0
    android::hardware::configstore::V1_0::ISurfaceFlingerConfigs::hasHDRDisplay retrieved: 0
I/OpenGLRenderer: Initialized EGL, version 1.4
D/OpenGLRenderer: Swap behavior 2
E/LB: fail to open file: No such file or directory
I/AssistStructure: Flattened final assist data: 3016 bytes, containing 1 windows, 10 views
I/DpmTcmClient: RegisterTcmMonitor from: $Proxy0
D/NetworkSecurityConfig: No Network Security Config specified, using platform default
E/Volley: [6558] BasicNetwork.performRequest: Unexpected response code 403 for http://192.168.43.26/android/v1/Registeruser.php
E/Volley: [6558] BasicNetwork.performRequest: Unexpected response code 403 for http://192.168.43.26/android/v1/Registeruser.php
I/Toast: Show toast from OpPackageName:com.example.researchprojectv2, PackageName:com.example.researchprojectv2
I/searchprojectv: ProcessProfilingInfo new_methods=153 is saved saved_to_disk=1 resolve_classes_delay=8000
```

Comment: Are you sending requests over HTTP or HTTPS? HTTP is not allowed unless you explicitly configure domains (and optionally subdomains) you talk to.

Comment: Post a full stack trace of the error, to make it easier to help to find out the problem.

Comment: I am sending it through HTTP only

Comment: Did you set any `android:networkSecurityConfig` in your `AndroidManifest.xml`? If not - that could be the issue. [Here is how to do it](https://developer.android.com/training/articles/security-config).

Comment: `NetworkSecurityConfig: No Network Security Config specified` - indeed, looks like network security config is the issue.

Comment: Post your network security configuration XML file and `<application>` tag from the manifest file.

Comment: @JeneaVranceanu Should I directly add this statement  `<application android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/network_security_config"` to my manifest file?

Comment: I'll post an answer and you'll try. Too long to write it all in a comment.

Comment: @JeneaVranceanu I don't know how to configure the file for networkSecurity can you provide some examples or tutorials that would be very much beneficial because I have only 10hours left to complete my project.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/217228/discussion-between-sumit-singh-and-jenea-vranceanu).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Google it more and more resolved it by my self, by adding port number after the IP in the URL.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like the issue you have is caused by talking to a server using HTTP protocol which is forbidden. Unless you explicitly configure hosts or IP addresses you need to talk to.

First of all, you should create `xml` resource directory under your project `res` directory (just a simple directory):

[image: XML resources directory]

Inside of it create an XML file. Name it how you want:

[image: XML file - network security config]

Inside of this file declare domains or IPs you would like to allow to use clear-text traffic (aka HTTP):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<network-security-config>
    <domain-config cleartextTrafficPermitted="true">
        <domain includeSubdomains="true">123.8.9.10</domain> 
        <!-- set domain name or IP instead of 123.8.9.10 -->
        <!-- do not use protocol prefixes as http:// or https:// ftp:// ... -->
    </domain-config>
</network-security-config>
```

Note the use of attribute that allows the application to use HTTP: `cleartextTrafficPermitted="true"`. **This attribute is required**.

And here is how to update `AndroidManifest.xml`:

```
<application
    android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/network_security_config" <!-- setting configuration -->

    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
    tools:ignore="UnusedAttribute">
    ...
</application>
```